# How to change the image when match the string in location path

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to change my logo when the path have contain correct string,  in the code bellow I tried to replace logo image to the new img when match the string: "?lang=ja" but not work

```
     var pathname = window.location.pathname;
     if(pathname.indexOf('?lang=ja') > -1){
       $("#logo img").attr("src", "http://demo-image-link.png");
     }     
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('?lang=ja') > -1) {
    $("#logo img").attr("src", "http://demo-image-link.png");
}
```

**Update:**

```
let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
if (urlParams.has('lang') && urlParams.get('lang') === 'ja') {
    $("#logo img").attr("src", "http://demo-image-link.png");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to check the parameter in the URL.

window.location.pathname will only give the path of the URL (It does not include the parameters).

You can use either one of the below to get the parameters
window.location.search --> returns all the parameters in the URL
window.location.href --> returns the complete path including the parameters.